# How to use find and a callback in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongoose

I have this function in Meteor:

```
Posts.find({_id: {$ne: ls._id}}, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {return console.error(err)};
    console.log("item: " + String(item));
});
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'updateSuggestions' Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation
```

This does work though:

```
Posts({_id: {$ne: ls._id}});
```

So I think its something with the callback function but I'm really not sure what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) doesn't take a callback as a parameter.

On the client, `find` is synchronous so the callback is unnecessary. On the server, `find` appears synchronous due to meteor's use of fibers.

Either way, you want something like this:

```
let posts = Posts.find({_id: {$ne: ls._id}}).fetch();
console.log(posts);
```

See [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for more details on `find` and `fetch`.

Comment: It also looks like @bren is looking for a single document with a query which is almost guaranteed to return many. @bren: if you're looking for a single document do `.findOne()` but then `$ne: ls._id` makes no sense.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'm looking for more than one. Thanks though.

Comment: Then `console.log("item: " + String(item));` won't mean much because you'll have a cursor, not a document.